# 9 Minute Long Running Query

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

[image][image]We recently stood up Documentum. We have a query that runs 9 minutes. We have applied indexes, this is a cotts product, the query runs against a view that the product creates.

Below is the syntax:

```
Declare @0 int
Declare @1 int

Set @0 ='1'
Set @1 ='1'

select all top 100 iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_object_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . object_name , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_object_type , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . title , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . subject , 
dm_repeating1_0 . authors , 
dm_repeating1_0 . keywords , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_application_type , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_status , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_creation_date , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_modify_date , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_modifier , 
iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_access_date , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_is_hidden , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_is_deleted , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_retention_date , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_archive , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_compound_architecture , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_link_resolved , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_reference_cnt , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_has_folder , dm_repeating1_0 . i_folder_id , dm_repeating1_0 . r_composite_id , dm_repeating1_0 . r_composite_label , dm_repeating1_0 . r_component_label , dm_repeating1_0 . r_order_no , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_link_cnt , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_link_high_cnt , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_assembled_from_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_frzn_assembly_cnt , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_has_frzn_assembly , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . resolution_label , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_is_virtual_doc , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_contents_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_content_type , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_page_cnt , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_content_size , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_full_text , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_storage_type , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_cabinet_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . owner_name , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . owner_permit , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . group_name , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . group_permit , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . world_permit , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_antecedent_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_chronicle_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_latest_flag , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_lock_owner , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_lock_date , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_lock_machine , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . log_entry , dm_repeating1_0 . r_version_label , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_branch_cnt , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_direct_dsc , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_immutable_flag , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_frozen_flag , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_has_events , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . acl_domain , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . acl_name , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_special_app , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_is_reference , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_creator_name , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_is_public , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_policy_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_resume_state , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_current_state , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_alias_set_id , dm_repeating1_0 . a_effective_date , dm_repeating1_0 . a_expiration_date , dm_repeating1_0 . a_publish_formats , dm_repeating1_0 . a_effective_label , dm_repeating1_0 . a_effective_flag , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_category , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . language_code , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_is_template , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_controlling_app , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_full_content_size , dm_repeating1_0 . a_extended_properties , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_is_signed , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . a_last_review_date , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_retain_until , dm_repeating1_0 . r_aspect_name , dm_repeating1_0 . i_retainer_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_partition , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_is_replica , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_vstamp , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . capture_county , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . program_area , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . deleted_on , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . ecs_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . delete_reason , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . deleted_by , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . capture_date , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . capture_user , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . is_fti , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . capture_source , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . category , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . capture_batch_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . capture_transaction_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . is_redacted , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . delete_status , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . form_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . sub_category , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . receipt_date , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . document_status , dm_repeating1_0 . recognition_data , dm_repeating1_0 . barcode_data , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . individual_type , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . is_confidential_ind , dm_repeating1_0 . individual_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . doc_imported , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . ecis_doc_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . compass_app_id , dm_repeating1_0 . application_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . capture_district , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . is_confidential_case , dm_repeating1_0 . cis_case_id , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . comments , dm_repeating1_0 . form_recognition_data , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . notice_id 
from iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc_sp iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc , iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc_rp dm_repeating1_0 
where ( iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_has_folder = @0 and iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . i_is_deleted = @1 ) 
and dm_repeating1_0 . r_object_id = iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_object_id 
order by iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc . r_creation_date desc
```

Here are the client stats.

```
Client Execution Time   8:14:54     
Query Profile Statistics            
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements    0       0
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 0       0
  Number of SELECT statements   1       1
  Rows returned by SELECT statements    1       1
  Number of transactions    0       0
Network Statistics          
  Number of server roundtrips   3       3
  TDS packets sent from client  5       5
  TDS packets received from server  148     148
  Bytes sent from client    10690       10690
  Bytes received from server    443508      443508
Time Statistics         
  Client processing time    7       7
  Total execution time  4292        4292
  Wait time on server replies   4285        4285
```

Here is the syntax for the view.

```
USE [DCTM_LOAD]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc_sp]    Script Date: 12/8/2015 8:25:10 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 CREATE  VIEW [dbo].[iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc_sp](r_object_id,object_name,
 r_object_type,title,subject,a_application_type,a_status,r_creation_date,
 r_modify_date,r_modifier,r_access_date,a_is_hidden,i_is_deleted,a_retention_date,
 a_archive,a_compound_architecture,a_link_resolved,i_reference_cnt,i_has_folder,
 r_link_cnt,r_link_high_cnt,r_assembled_from_id,r_frzn_assembly_cnt,r_has_frzn_assembly,resolution_label,r_is_virtual_doc,i_contents_id,
 a_content_type,r_page_cnt,r_content_size,a_full_text,a_storage_type,i_cabinet_id,owner_name,owner_permit,group_name,group_permit,
 world_permit,i_antecedent_id,i_chronicle_id,i_latest_flag,r_lock_owner,r_lock_date,r_lock_machine,log_entry,i_branch_cnt,i_direct_dsc,
 r_immutable_flag,r_frozen_flag,r_has_events,acl_domain,acl_name,a_special_app,i_is_reference,r_creator_name,r_is_public,r_policy_id,
 r_resume_state,r_current_state,r_alias_set_id,a_category,language_code,a_is_template,a_controlling_app,r_full_content_size,a_is_signed,
 a_last_review_date,i_retain_until,i_partition,i_is_replica,i_vstamp,capture_county,program_area,deleted_on,ecs_id,delete_reason,
 deleted_by,capture_date,capture_user,is_fti,capture_source,category,capture_batch_id,capture_transaction_id,is_redacted,
 delete_status,form_id,sub_category,receipt_date,document_status,individual_type,is_confidential_ind,doc_imported,ecis_doc_id,compass_app_id,capture_district,
 is_confidential_case,comments,notice_id,i_property_bag) 
 WITH SCHEMABINDING  AS  SELECT WB_.r_object_id,WB_.object_name,
 WB_.r_object_type,WB_.title,WB_.subject,WB_.a_application_type,WB_.a_status,WB_.r_creation_date,WB_.r_modify_date,WB_.r_modifier,
 WB_.r_access_date,WB_.a_is_hidden,WB_.i_is_deleted,WB_.a_retention_date,WB_.a_archive,WB_.a_compound_architecture,WB_.a_link_resolved,
 WB_.i_reference_cnt,WB_.i_has_folder,WB_.r_link_cnt,WB_.r_link_high_cnt,WB_.r_assembled_from_id,WB_.r_frzn_assembly_cnt,WB_.r_has_frzn_assembly,
 WB_.resolution_label,WB_.r_is_virtual_doc,WB_.i_contents_id,WB_.a_content_type,WB_.r_page_cnt,WB_.r_content_size,WB_.a_full_text,WB_.a_storage_type,
 WB_.i_cabinet_id,WB_.owner_name,WB_.owner_permit,WB_.group_name,WB_.group_permit,WB_.world_permit,WB_.i_antecedent_id,WB_.i_chronicle_id,WB_.i_latest_flag,
 WB_.r_lock_owner,WB_.r_lock_date,WB_.r_lock_machine,WB_.log_entry,WB_.i_branch_cnt,WB_.i_direct_dsc,WB_.r_immutable_flag,WB_.r_frozen_flag,WB_. r_has_events,
 WB_.acl_domain,WB_.acl_name,WB_.a_special_app,WB_.i_is_reference,WB_.r_creator_name,WB_.r_is_public,WB_.r_policy_id,WB_.r_resume_state,
 WB_.r_current_state,WB_.r_alias_set_id,WB_.a_category,WB_.language_code,WB_.a_is_template,WB_.a_controlling_app,
 WB_.r_full_content_size,WB_.a_is_signed,WB_.a_last_review_date,WB_.i_retain_until,WB_.i_partition,WB_.i_is_replica,
 WB_.i_vstamp,CBB_.capture_county,CBB_.program_area,CBB_.deleted_on,CBB_.ecs_id,CBB_.delete_reason,CBB_.deleted_by,CBB_.capture_date,
 CBB_.capture_user,CBB_.is_fti,CBB_.capture_source,CBB_.category,CBB_.capture_batch_id,CBB_.capture_transaction_id,CBB_.is_redacted,
 CBB_.delete_status,CBB_.form_id,CBB_.sub_category,CBB_.receipt_date,CBB_.document_status,GBB_.individual_type,GBB_.is_confidential_ind,
 KBB_.doc_imported,KBB_.ecis_doc_id,KBB_.compass_app_id,KBB_.capture_district,KBB_.is_confidential_case,KBB_.comments,KBB_.notice_id,WB_.i_property_bag 
 FROM dbo.iciss_dhs_elig_ind_doc_s KBB_,dbo.ecm_dhs_ind_doc_s GBB_,dbo.ecm_dhs_doc_s CBB_,dbo.dm_sysobject_s WB_ 
 WHERE (WB_.r_object_id=KBB_.r_object_id 
 AND (WB_.r_object_id=CBB_.r_object_id 
 AND (CBB_.r_object_id=KBB_.r_object_id 
 AND (WB_.r_object_id=GBB_.r_object_id 
 AND (CBB_.r_object_id=GBB_.r_object_id 
 AND GBB_.r_object_id=KBB_.r_object_id)))))
GO
```

Looking for some guidance how could we tune this query.

Comment: can you provide a better print screen? I can't read it. it's using index seek? scan? are there some lookups?What indexes do you have? what versions of sql server it is?looks like 2008.Oh..try to give us the `create table` sintax too

Comment: This is sql server 2012..it is index seek, i'll try to give a better picture.

Comment: I see a number of Clustered Index Scans returning a load of rows (please don't say it is Index Seek...)....They then get filtered into barely any rows. Something tells me the indexes you have applied are not good enough so it would be a good idea to show the indexes

Comment: Here is the xml for the execution plan.

Comment: Don't post *pictures* of the plan. Post the actual showplan XML.

Comment: Can you post the table DDL as well along with plan XML?

Comment: The XML is too long. The ddl for the view is already posted.

Comment: You can use pastebin for XML and I mean to post the DDL for base tables .. So we can recreate your scenario and help you out.

Comment: I can not because the ddl exceeds the limitations of stackexchange.

Comment: @MikeKraus Please read my comment. I am asking you to upload it to **pastebin** and reference the link here. Does it help ?

Comment: pastebin is blocked here.

Comment: You are defining `@0 and @1` as int and then setting them to **string**  `Set @0 ='1'` !

Answer (score 2):

What trace flags are enabled at system and session level?

Are the r_object_id columns the pks and/or clustered index keys for their respective tables?
Are the r_object_id columns ascending keys in their respective tables?

You can find out whether SQL Server thinks the r_object_id columns are ascending keys in the 'leading column type' column available in 'dbcc show_statistics' output when trace flag 2388 is enabled at session level, as below.

If the r_object_id columns are ascending keys that experience significant growth between statistics updates, you may want to consider trace flags 2389 + 2390 or trace flag 4139 to mitigate the ascending key problem.

The ascending key problem would result in row estimates of 1 for filters beyond the highest RANGE_HI_KEY in the histogram, potentially resulting in bad plan choice if there are thousands or more of actual rows at the point in the plan.

Trace flags 2389 + 2390
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianjo/archive/2006/04/24/582227.aspx
http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2013/02/statistics-on-ascending-keys/

Trace flag 4139
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2952101

[image: TraceFlag2388]